# Liferay Kafka integration

Tags: java, liferay

Over internet I didn't got reference to implement Kafka in liferay.

Below are the requirements needs to be implemented

- Push the message to Kafka topic
- Poll and receive message from Kafka topic.

Tried below, but unable to receive message from kafka after pushed from kafka terminal

Dependencies :

compileInclude "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.9.2"

compileInclude "org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:3.3.1"

Code:

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafkaStreams;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaStreamsConfiguration;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG;
import static org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG;
import static org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG;
import static org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG;

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
    KafkaStreamsConfiguration kStreamsConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-app");
        props.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
    }
}
```

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Log;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogFactoryUtil;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component(immediate = true)
public class KafkaMessageReceiver {

    public static Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(KafkaMessageReceiver.class);

    @Async
    @KafkaListener(
        topics = "liferay-topic",
        concurrency = "2"
    )
    @Transactional
    public void handleMessage(String payload) {
        _log.info(payload);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unable to receive message from Kafka after pushed from Kafka terminal

Comment: You're running in an OSGi container, not a spring runtime. The spring runtime does not necessarily know how to wire your listener in that environment. But other than this pointer, I can't provide more details. And as you tag liferay-6, liferay-6 and liferay-theme: you might want to specify what they have to do with your question. I'm assuming that you're not running version 6.x, or that your Kafka listener is a visual component for the Look&Feel. (Tags edited)